# link_to and passing variables

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a page: `my-account/my-templates/view/1` - which simply uses the `id` field of `1` to display the item

What I'm wanting to do is to create a copy action, that simply takes all the values in this item and creates a new item

I have a `link_to()` which holds the following:

```
<?php echo link_to('Copy', '@copy_template', array('id' => $template->getId())); ?>
```

I'm passing in the id of the template.

Can I access this id in the copy action?

EDIT:

Actions:

```
public function executeViewTemplate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->template = Doctrine_Core::getTable('UserTemplate')->getUserTemplate($request->getParameter('id'));
}

public function executeTemplateCopy(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $this->id = $request->getParameter('id');
   // get the passed template id 
}
```

Templates:

viewTemplateSuccess.php

```
<?php echo link_to('Copy', '@copy_template', array('id' => $sf_request->getParameter('id'), 'class'=>'button green')); ?>
```

templateCopySuccess.php

```
<?php echo "ID". $id;?> --> doesn't return the passed id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an action, you can retrieve a parameter using:

```
$id = $request->getParameter('id');
```

For example, if you have this action:

```
public function executeCopyTemplate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $id = $request->getParameter('id');
}
```

And from a template:

```
<?php $id = $sf_request->getParameter('id') ?>
```

In your case:

```
<?php echo link_to('Copy', '@copy_template?id='.$sf_request->getParameter('id')); ?>
```

Comment: The main problem is the URL no longer contains the URL, it will be `my-account/my-templates/copy` - but i need to pass the id from the `view` action, if that makes sense?

Comment: If `1` is given as a parameter called `id` in `my-account/my-templates/view/1`, I've update my answer in this case.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have a URL my-account/my-templates/view/1. When I click on `Copy` the URL becomes, my-account/my-templates/copy - without the id. I know I can access via the request parameter, but I need to pass this id value to my copy action

Comment: i was hoping I could pass it into the link_to() and access it in the action

Comment: Try to use the last code block I put in my answer. As @cobra said, second array parameter is for html option, not for the route parameter.

Comment: I didn't notice the last code block you posted. It seems to work great! Although it does add an id in the query string

Comment: Can you post your routing.yml for the route `copy_template` ?

Answer (score 0):

The array at the end of the link_to function alters HTML attributes like class and id.  It doesnt pass url parameters normally.  THis will work:

```
<?php echo link_to('Copy', '@copy_template?id='. $template->getId(), array()); ?>
```